# merge dynamic range using vba code and then loop

Tags: vba

i need help to create a code to merge five cells in a column from column 1 to 25 then from column 30 to 40 and then looping down the rows for merging again five cells.

For example i have a sheet containing data from A3 to au3. Here i want that every cell in range A3:A7, B3:B7, C3:C7 and so on up to Y3:Y7 should merge then leaving the range Z3:AD3 as it is and merge next range from AE3:AE7 to AN3:AN7.

Then loop down the rows to merge again five cells

i am using this code but it is too complex and works very slow and is not working " For each worksheet in wks"

any prompt help...................

```
Sub mergecells()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, x As Integer
On Error Resume Next
With Wks("Employee Data")
For each Worksheet In Wks
For i = 1 To 24

Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(7, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(8, i), Cells(12, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(13, i), Cells(17, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(18, i), Cells(22, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(23, i), Cells(27, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(28, i), Cells(32, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(33, i), Cells(37, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(38, i), Cells(42, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(43, i), Cells(47, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(48, i), Cells(52, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(53, i), Cells(57, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(58, i), Cells(62, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(63, i), Cells(67, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(68, i), Cells(72, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(73, i), Cells(77, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(78, i), Cells(82, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(83, i), Cells(87, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(88, i), Cells(92, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(93, i), Cells(97, i)).Merge
Range(Cells(98, i), Cells(102, i)).Merge

For j = 33 To 37

Range(Cells(3, j), Cells(7, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(8, j), Cells(12, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(13, j), Cells(17, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(18, j), Cells(22, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(23, j), Cells(27, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(28, j), Cells(32, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(33, j), Cells(37, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(38, j), Cells(42, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(43, j), Cells(47, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(48, j), Cells(52, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(53, j), Cells(57, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(58, j), Cells(62, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(63, j), Cells(67, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(68, j), Cells(72, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(73, j), Cells(77, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(78, j), Cells(82, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(83, j), Cells(87, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(88, j), Cells(92, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(93, j), Cells(97, j)).Merge
Range(Cells(98, j), Cells(102, j)).Merge

For x = 41 To 48

Range(Cells(3, x), Cells(7, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(8, x), Cells(12, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(13, x), Cells(17, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(18, x), Cells(22, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(23, x), Cells(27, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(28, x), Cells(32, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(33, x), Cells(37, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(38, x), Cells(42, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(43, x), Cells(47, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(48, x), Cells(52, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(53, x), Cells(57, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(58, x), Cells(62, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(63, x), Cells(67, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(68, x), Cells(72, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(73, x), Cells(77, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(78, x), Cells(82, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(83, x), Cells(87, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(88, x), Cells(92, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(93, x), Cells(97, x)).Merge
Range(Cells(98, x), Cells(102, x)).Merge

Next         
Next
Next
Next
Columns.VertxcalAlxgnment = xlVAlxgnCenter
Applxcatxon.DxsplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried editing the code using with statement for other sheets but the problem is that code is again working very slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will merge ranges according to your post in `Worksheets("Employee Data")`, the code runs in less than a second.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeCells()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        For lRow = 3 To 33 Step 5 ' you can increase beyond row 33
            For lCol = 1 To 25
                .Range(.Cells(lRow, lCol), .Cells(lRow + 4, lCol)).Merge
            Next lCol
            For lCol = 30 To 40
                .Range(.Cells(lRow, lCol), .Cells(lRow + 4, lCol)).Merge
            Next lCol
        Next lRow
    End With
Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks this codes works fine for one sheet in worksheet. How to extend the same code for all the sheets in worksheet

Comment: @AtulKantGodiyal try the edited code to do this for all sheets